# Java Coding; Leap Year or Not a Leap Year

Tags: java, if-statement

Write a java program to compute leap year. To determine is a year is a leap year, use the following logic:

- The year must be divisible by 4.
- Starting from 1582, if the year is divisible by 100, it must also be divisible by 400. Thus,
  the year 1700 is not a leap year, but 2000 is. However, 1500 is leap year since it was before 1582, the adoption year of Gregorian calendar.

(Note: I am using java.util.Scanner; and if else statements.)

Comment: Can you show the code/work you have done until now?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is code writing request. "[Questions asking for homework help must include a **summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem**, and a **description of the difficulty you are having solving it**.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)"

Comment: Most countries didn't adopt the Gregorian calendar until long after 1582. Greece adopted it in the 1930s

Answer (score 4):

Assuming this is NOT your homework, this is the best way,

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
.
.
int year = 1582;
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
if(gc.isLeapYear(year))
    System.out.println("Leap year");
else
    System.out.println("Not a leap year");
```